# Mock prompts in Python 2.x.x for username and password credentials

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write a unit test in python that tests a username and password entry. I am using prompts for user input for both the username and password.

I have two separate functions that prompt the user for username and password. Both functions then check length. The password function also checks for exceptions, that were made by us, if the password length is zero. Are their ways to mock these exceptions?

I am struggling because I can get passed the username prompt but the pytest script holds after the username input. Is there a way to mock both username and password?

I am fairly new to python and I have looked through documentation but everything I have seen is usually for Python 3.x.x which we currently aren't implementing at this time. Any help would be much appreciated.

I think the **init** function is actually causing most of the headaches I am having. Is there a way around this?

```
class Login(object):
    def __init__(self, args, env="test"):
       created_token = self.login()

    def login(self):

        username = self.args.username
        if len(username) == 0:
            username = self._get_username()

        password = self.args.password
        if len(password) == 0:
            password = self._get_password(username)

    def _get_username(self):
        return prompt('%s Username (%s): ' % (self.domain)

    def _get_password(self):
        if password is None:
             password = prompt_sensitive('%s Password: ' % self.domain)
         try:
         except ParseError,e:
              print "ParseError message"
         except ClientError,e:
              print "ClientError message"
```

Comment: Why are you using prompts? Why not test against known positive and known negative values. Prompting will kill any automated testing.

Comment: The prompts are for the original code that I am trying to write the unit test for. Sorry I didn't really make that clear in the first part

Comment: If you posted a minimal example of the prompts I could probably give you a good answer.

Comment: @2rs2ts I uploaded some of the stripped code that hopefully clears up my issue. Thanks

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code that you posted, and it's incomplete. How are `prompt` and `prompt_sensitive` defined? What is `password` in `_get_password`? etc. can you please correct these problems first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dependency injection to inject the prompt.

```
def password_function(input_func=None):
   input_func = input_func or input
   ...

def test_password_function(self, ...):
   fake_input = Mock()
   ...
   result = password_function(fake_input)
```

This won't break existing code since the previous call signature is valid. e.g. `password_function()`. However if you don't have access to change the code then you can patch the `input` function.

```
import __builtin__

@mock.patch(__builtins__, 'input', return_value=...)
def test_password_function(self, mock_input):
```

Comment: What if I can't change the original functions?